# Polymorphic relations + HasMany

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism

I've been trying to figure this out for the past 3 days with no improvement.

Basically, I have a model called **ContentStack** with a polymorphic relation called **contentable** to multiple other models ( each containing a different type of content like VideoContent, ImageContent, TextContent. Each have different columns ).

I'd like to be able to dynamically get a ContentStack's related model based on the contentable_type column. Which works using a polymorphic relation like below.

```
class Contentstack extends Model
{
protected $table = 'contentstack';

protected $fillable = [
    'appId','contentable_id','contentable_type'
];

public function contentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

}

The issue I'm having is, each related model actually should have many rows related and not just one, just like a HasMany relation, like below ( Notice the contentstackID field ) :

```
class VideoContent extends Model
{
    //
protected $table = 'video_content';

protected $fillable = [
    'contentstackID','image','category'

];

}
```

In the end what I'm trying to achieve is :

Have ContentStack automatically figure out which model to fetch the content from, based on the contentable_type column, but get all rows from the related model table instead of just one ( based on the contentstackId in related model )

Maybe there's a different design pattern that I should be using here but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: please look at the doc; https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations there is `$this-> morphMany()` function that you could use

Comment: I'm looking for a OneToMany ( One Contentstack to Many Contents from different models ) not Many to Many. 
I did check out the morphMany docs but it does not help me achieve what I'm looking for